# Android custom settings

Tags: android

Welcome.
How to make your own design option?

Something like this:

[image]

I just want to make my own design options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those seem like just custom buttons with custom backgrounds and text on them..

Google android custom themes and android styles.xml